# Is ColdFusion installed / running - on Linux?

Tags: linux, apache, coldfusion

I am not familiar with ColdFusion, hence this basic question.

I have a Linux Server running Apache. I need to determine if ColdFusion is running/enabled on this machine.

Should i look at Apache Config files like httpd.conf to find if ColdFusion is enabled there?

### EDIT

I can see a response on: http: //server/CFIDE/administrator 
Does this conclude that Cold Fusion is running on port 80? 
There is Apache on this box, on port 443 (ssl). Not sure if port 80 too is Apache or that was Cold Fusion.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can check if the process is running:

```
$ ps -A | grep coldf
  3376 ?        00:00:00 coldfusion9
  3378 ?        1-05:14:46 coldfusion9
```

You can check the httpd.conf, if the module is loading:

```
LoadModule jrun_module /opt/coldfusion9/runtime/lib/wsconfig/1/mod_jrun22.so
```

You can access the ColdFusion Administrator - it doesn't necessary need an apache.

```
http://server/CFIDE/administrator
```

Comment: On a secure system, CF administrator is ideally limited to local/vpn, so it might not be `http://server/cfide/administrator` but instead `http://localhost:8500/cfide/administrator` or something else.

Comment: Also, CF10 replaced JRun with Tomcat, so should check for other connectors - mod_jk, mod_proxy, etc - searching the config files for `fusion` is probably a good idea (might be coldfusion or cfusion).

Comment: da_didi> I can see a response on: http: //server/CFIDE/administrator , does that mean Cold Fusion is running on port 80? 'ps -ef|grep cold' , gives me no result, but that could be becz i don't have root privileges.  What should i conclude? Apache too is running on this box.

Comment: No, Apache will be running on port 80, and two things can't use the same port for the same host. It'll be going via a connector to a different port (e.g. 8500) - check for mod_jrun, mod_jk, mod_proxy, etc in the Apache config files. Also look for things like `cfusion` `tomcat` `java` in the process list.

Comment: But Apache could be running on port 443, and cold fusion on port 80

Comment: Apache is running on both port 80 (HTTP) and 443 (HTTPS). Look at the config files for confirmation.